# Symfony2 - Empty CSRF token

Tags: php, symfony, csrf

I deployed a Symfony2 app, but all the forms have empty csrf tokens. This html comes from firebug. As you can see, the tag is properly rendered, but no value is assigned.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="category[_token]" id="category__token">
```

In my controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CategoryForm(), new Category());
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    (...)
}
```

In the template, the form is inside of a bootstrap 3 modal.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Voeg een tariefplan toe</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form_label(form.name) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form_label(form.parent) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.parent, {'attr':{ 'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form_label(form.sizes) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.sizes, {'attr':{ 'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form_label(form.description) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.description, {'attr':{ 'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
                    </div>

                    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</button>
                    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr':{ 'class': 'btn btn-primary' }}) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I also created a gist for the CategoryForm class : http://goo.gl/6NWTkB.

Anyone who knows what I'm missing here?

Comment: Is that category entity is a collection?

Comment: can you post your categoryForm?

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the value:

```
<input type="hidden" value={{ csrf_token('category') }}"" name="category[_token]" id="category__token">
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

`{{ form_end(form) }}` should output your token so there's no need to have: `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`.

If you have a very large form php might truncate your request vars. Have a look at `max_input_vars` in your `php.ini`. Default is 1000 I believe.